# PHP - Mongo - $or

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using PHP/Mongo to query a data set like the following:

```
{
  description:
  {
    0:
      {level: (some int 0-50)},
    1:
      {level: (some int 0-50)},

  ...

    n:
      {level: (some int 0-50)}
   }
 }
```

How do I write the function, in php, that will build a dynamic query that searches for a level 40 and above, using $or and based on the number of description keys (0 ... n)?

What I currently have for a manual query is not working (I have a feeling it's because in some entries description.1, 2, 3 do not exist):

```
find("$or":{"description.0.level":[40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50],"descriptio‌​n.1.level":[40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50],"description.2.level":[40,41,42,43,‌​44,45,46,47,48,49,50],"description.3.level":[40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]}})
```

It gives me an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message '$and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array'

So, I need a function that will build the query dynamically, and work :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those interested, here is my final code for this problem (works).

```
$y = 0;
$descriptionLevels = 10; // set to 'n' levels as needed ...
while($y < $descriptionLevels){
    $filter['$or'][]['description.' . $y . '.level']['$in'] = range($startLevel, $endLevel);
    $y++;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `$or` query's value itself should be an array.
`{$or : [...]}`

Please see the standard example in the [MongoDB documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or).

You will probably also want to use an operator such as `$in` (or `$lt` and `$gt` in combination) to select which description level you are interested in, rather than enumerating each value.